# why does my php session information behave differently on a different server

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple web site php/jquery/mysql etc. Currently I've a pretty simple login system where once the user logs in a session variable is set that is referenced to confirm if they're still logged in on other pages. Code is:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['member_id'] = $member_id_for_session;
$_SESSION['handle'] = $user_handle;
```

I have a variety of functions in util files that make use of this such as:

```
function echoUserHandle() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['handle'])) {
        echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['handle'];
    } else {
        echo "You are not logged in";
    }
}
```

and

```
function checkLoggedIn() {

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
}
```

this works fine on my MAMP server on my mac using chrome however when I push it out to my remote server I get inconsistent views of the data even on the same browser I use to dev on. I see this only by the fact that some pages show the status "You are not logged in" whilst some display the correct user id.

Also once a user is logged out the session is destroyed fully using:

```
        unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
        unset($_SESSION['member_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['handle']);
        $_SESSION = array();

        if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
            error_log("unsetting cookie:" . session_name(), 0);
            $params = session_get_cookie_params();
            error_log("cookie params:" . $params, 0);
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
        }

        session_destroy();
```

this might be overkill but, when I log back in as a different user on some pages it still displays the previous logged in user. This suggests something wrong with the session doesn't it?

Can anyone suggest an approach to debug this, I've done a lot of dev in other fields but php is still new to me.

Many thanks

Comment: note: learn to use the booleans directly, eg: `return isset($_SESSION['logged_in']);`

Comment: make sure your error reporting level is E_ALL. if anything wrong it will show you the reason. that is the first step you can take to debug anything in php

Comment: hehe school boy error for the booleans :)